# What is the most straightforward way to take an HTTP POST and convert that into an ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware, asp.net-core-2.1

I have signed authentication string that I would like to send to an ASP.NET Core instance, and have that string validated, and converted into a User with corresponding roles.

Assuming that all user and claims information is stored within the HTTP POST or GET request, how would I convert this into something usable, and would cooperate with other coexisting schemes that may exist?

Comment: How is the signed authentication string created?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik The unauthenticated user is redirected to a well known URL that's is intercepted by a browser plugin or a mobile app.  The app will then HTTP POST the data back to an ASP.NET Core URL on  `./custom-provider`.  I'd need to initiate the first redirect (optionally work with other social providers too), and then convert the response back into an Identity with Claims.  I'm just not sure where to put the necessary redirect, validation, and claims translation logic

Comment: I suppose the question could be rephrased, how do I create a custom social provider that "does something different" during the validation phase of the OAuth trip